# how to set path environment variable

Tags: windows-xp, environment-variables

I want to compile a code in software which is needed to call visual c++;My Os is windows cp professional;
 I've installed visual studio professional v10.but it still shows an error message indicating "check if bin directory of your visual c++ is included in the path environment variable",
where this action must be done?

---

I added that Path but now it says " Check that Visual C++ has been installed correctly" how I gotta check? I executed a program in Visual C++ and it s working nicely.

Comment: Duplicate question, for answer, see: http://superuser.com/questions/163891/environment-variables-windows7/163898#163898

Comment: Those instructions are not very good.

Comment: Nothing wrong with those instructions, although I didn't know of setx.

Comment: I think it is hard to edit long environmental variables in that GUI and it also seems a bit perverse!

Comment: Run => %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

```
System Properties (press windows key + pause/break)
Advanced
Environment Variables
System variables
```

Add the required path there

Answer (score 4):

In a CMD prompt, type:

```
path
```

To add to your user account path:

```
setx path "%path%;C:\foo"
```

For the system path:

```
setx path "%path%;C:\foo" -m
```

Comment: I added that Path but now it says " Check that Visual C++ has been installed correctly" 
how I gotta check?
I executed a program in Visual C++ and it s working nicely.

Comment: `%PATH%` contains both _user_ *and* _machine_ components of the environment variable PATH. Running e.g. the command `setx path "%path%;C:\foo" -m` will effectively merge the two which is undesirable in most cases. Aside from that it will also overwrite the unexpanded paths with expanded ditto (`%SYSTEMROOT%\System32` becomes e.g. `C:\Windows\System32`).

Comment: @mandrake: Yes, you're right.  It would be better to `echo %PATH% | clip` to get the path into the clipboard, edit it in Notepad and then use the full unexpanded path (with no duplicates) in the command above instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your visual studio installation should have added a menu item for under Tools for the VS 2008 command prompt - this will usually set the appropriate environment for you.