# How to make a cmd 'runnable as administrator' under windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, command-line, runas

I have written as small `.cmd` file to be executed as an administrator. I am trying to set its options as 'Run as Administrator' but the check box is not accessible.

[image: Run As Administrator]

Why? How to solve this issue? I am administrator on my PC (Windows 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Shortcut to the `.CMD` you want to launch (Right-click-->Create Shortcut, or drag-drop with <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed)

Go into the shortcut's Properties-->Shortcut Tab-->Advanced-->Check-mark Run as Administrator

Then launch with the Shortcut instead.

Comment: Thanks. It did the trick. For the records: I had to create a 'set location=C:/Users/etc...' variable in my .cmd and use it with each command to make it work.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Have you considered setting the environment variable permanently instead?  Check out SetX, and/or this question: [how to set path environment variable](http://superuser.com/questions/174720/how-to-set-path-environment-variable/174724#174724) amongst others, for some info on that. :)

Comment: The thing is that I may need to modify it in the future and it is only used in the .cmd. It's not really necessary to make it global (in my case).

Answer (score 2):

[runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772672%28WS.10%29.aspx) might come to some use for you

Comment: Keep in mind `runas` only elevates commands if you use the builtin Admin account's credentials and you have autoapproval mode on.  Otherwise this will fail due to UAC.